# How do i extract data from JSON using JS

Tags: javascript, web

```
{ "errors":
          [
            { "value":"k@d.c",
              "msg":"Email is not valid",
              "param":"email",
              "location":"body"
            }
          ]
 }
```

I wanna extract the msg from this json object. How do i do this?

Comment: Parse using JSON.parse and then access the desired property

Comment: What did you attempt that is not working?

Comment: @CodeManiac I tried that but it threw a token error

Answer (score 1):

```
const jsonContent = `{"errors":[{"value":"k@d.c","msg":"Email is not valid","param":"email","location":"body"}]}`;
const jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonContent);
const errorMessage = jsObject.errors[0].msg;
```

This will result in:

```
{ 
   "errors":[ 
      { 
         "value":"k@d.c",
         "msg":"Email is not valid",
         "param":"email",
         "location":"body"
      }
   ]
}
```

[UPDATE]
Sorry, didn't see you asked just for the msg property. Edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(str)` like so

```
var t = '{"errors":[{"value":"k@d.c","msg":"Email is not valid","param":"email","location":"body"}]}';
var msg = JSON.parse(t)["errors"][0]["msg"];
```